# restriction map of divisor class groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I have a probably silly question about proof of Proposition 6.6.5(b) from Hartshorne (Algebraic Geometry) on page 133:

*Proposition 6.5.* Let $X$ satisfy (*), let $Z$ be a proper closed subset of $X$, and
let $U = X - Z$. Then:

(a) there is a surjective homomorphism $\operatorname{Cl} X \to \operatorname{Cl} U$ defined by $D =
\sum n_i Y_i \mapsto \sum n_i (Y_i \cap U)$, where we ignore those $Y_i \cup U$ which are empty;

(b) if $codim(Z,X) \le 2$, then $\operatorname{Cl} X \to \operatorname{Cl} U$ is an isomorphism;

A few words about notations:

The condition (*) requires that $X$ is a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in
codimension one.

The Weil group $\operatorname{Div} X$ consists of Weil divisors $D= \sum n_i Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are prime divisors, the $n_i$ are integers, and only finitely many $n_i$ are different from zero. If all the $n_i \le 0$, we say
that D is effective. We obtain $\operatorname{Cl} X$ if we mod out effective Weil divisors from $\operatorname{Div} X$.

For sake of completeness that prime divisor $Y$ is a closed integral subscheme $Y \subset X$ of codimension one (comp. page 130).

The proof of Proposition 6.5 (b):

The groups $\operatorname{Div} X$ and $\operatorname{Cl} X$ depend only on subsets of codimension
$1$, so removing a closed subset $Z$ of codimension $ \le 2$ doesn't change anything.

What does it mean "removing a closed subset $Z$ of codimension $ \le 2$ doesn't change anything"? What Hartshorne means concretely by "anything" here? Does it simply mean that $Y_i \cap (X -Z) \neq \varnothing$ for all prime divisors $Y_i$ and $Z \subset X$ of codimension $\le 2$? Or what does this formulation could else mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that all of the information we need to figure out what's going on with divisors on a scheme $X$ satisfying (*) is accessible by looking just at the codimension-one points: two divisors $D,D'$ are the same iff there's a rational function $f$ so that $D-D'=div(f)$. But we can determine exactly what $div(f)$ is by looking at $f$'s valuation at each codimension 1 point of $X$. Altering codimension-two behavior doesn't change the stalk at the generic point of $X$ nor can it remove the generic point of any codimension-one irreducible variety, so it doesn't change our method of detecting when two divisors are equal or our data we use to perform this task. This is how I'd interpret "anything" in this text.

Comment: The second part of you answer I not understand. You wrote "every irreducible prime divisor is of codimension $1$, which means such a subvariety must meet every closed subvariety of codimnsion $2$, as $2+1≤n$. Why last condition imply that that each codimension $1$ subvariety must meet every codimension $2$ subvariety? Thinking about vector spaces it becomes obviuos by intuition but I cannot find a "formal" argument. In addition why this example shows that the approach "Does it simply mean that $Y_i \cap (X -Z) \neq \varnothing$ for all prime divisors $Y_i$ and $Z⊂X$ of codimension $≤2$" fails?

Comment: I think I misread what you intended to say there - I inserted or removed an extra "not" somewhere. You are correct that $Y_i\cap(X\setminus Z)$ cannot be empty if $Z$ is codimension 2. The claim I was referring to is the projective dimension theorem, available in Hartshorne I.7, for instance: "If $X,Y\subset \Bbb P^n$ are irreducible closed subvarieties of codimension $r,s$ respectively, then every irreducible component of $X\cap Y$ is codimension at least $r+s$. In particular, if $r+s\leq n$, this intersection is nonempty."

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "we can determine exactly what $div(f)$ is by looking at f's valuation at each codimension $1$ point of $X$. Altering codimension-two behavior doesn't change the stalk at the generic point of $X$ nor the stalk at the generic point of any codimension-one irreducible variety"?

Comment: I think about this as follows: assume $x$ is codim $1$ point. Let $S_x$ be the stalk of $x$ which is $1$ dimensional.  I think that by "valuation at $x$" you mean that you firstly consider $f$ as element of $S_x$ and then kill the maximal ideal $M_x$ of $S_x$, i.e. $f \mod M_x$, right? And if you alter $f$ only on stalks of codim $2$ points you mean that for each such $y$ there exist codim $1$ point $x'$ with $M_{x'} \subset M_y$ and the "alternation"

Comment: of $f$ at codim $2$ point $y$ mean that you modify $f$ by an element $r \in M_y -M_{x'} $? This modification are not recognized by valuations at codim $1$ points as $r$ becomes in $S_{x'}$ invertible and thus $f$ and $rf$ give the same divisor $div(f)$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I should have written "it does not remove any codimension-one points". My apologies, I think I must have been tired when writing the answer. If you're confused about what $div(f)$ is, I think you should go back and reread the definitions: it's a linear combination of prime divisors, and we can check the coefficients on prime divisors by looking at the valuation of $f$ at their generic points. There's no need to do any of what you're talking about in your last 3 comments.

Comment: What you mean by "altering codimension-two behavior" precisely? Take $div(f)= \sum_Y v(f)_Y$. Then your "alternating" means adding or removing subvarieties of codim $\ge 2$ to or from $div(f)$?

Comment: Your question is about removing codimension two sets from $X$. This is what that phrase addresses, with "altering" chosen because once you remove $Z$ from $X$, you can think of "re-adding" $Z$ to $X$ to go back from $X\setminus Z$ to $X$ (though you're going to need to think about how to do this if you don't already know what $Z$ was and how you removed it).